# Unicode error in python 3.5 conda while implementing RenderTree function

Tags: python, eclipse, unicode, conda

I am using anytree package for creating tree.

```
udo = Node("Udo")
marc = Node("Marc", parent=udo)
print(RenderTree(udo))
```

While using RenderTree function, I am getting unicode error as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Neelakshi\workspace\LogisticRegression\TypeHierarchyTest.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       print(RenderTree(udo))   File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in
>   encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 14-16: character maps to

I have seen similar threads for this issue but could not find solution for it. I am running this sample program from eclipse and not from command line. Following are package details :

```
python: 3.5.1
conda: 4.3.24
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing Eclipse  encoding settings to Utf-8. It was cp1252 before.